# C++ To C# Marshaling of Nested Structs with Union

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling, unmanaged

I have to use C++ .dll with C# code. I need to call a method:

```
THERMALSDK_API short PASCAL GetIRHeaders(HANDLE handle, IRF_IR_FILE_HEADER_T* header, IRF_IR_DATA_HEADER_T* addedInfo, unsigned long *curPos);
```

To do so, i've created a simple wrapper:

```
public class COXAccessor : ICOXAccessor
{
    [DllImport("ThermalCamDll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, ExactSpelling = false,
        EntryPoint = "GetIRHeaders")]
    private static extern ReturnCode GetIRHeaders(out IntPtr handle, out IRF_IR_FILE_HEADER_T header, out IRF_IR_DATA_HEADER_T addedInfo, out uint curPos);

    public ReturnCode GetIRHeadersInternal(out IntPtr handle, out IRF_IR_FILE_HEADER_T header,
        out IRF_IR_DATA_HEADER_T addedInfo, out uint curPos)
    {
        return GetIRHeaders(out handle, out header, out addedInfo, out curPos);
    }
}
```

As you can see this method requires few objects to be passed in. The most complicated of it is IRF_IR_DATA_HEADER_T and it nested structure IRF_SAVEDATA_T:

```
/* Structure of IR data header */
typedef struct  
{
    BYTE                    dynamic_range;          // IRF_DYNAMIC_RANGE_T 
  
    IRF_SAVEDATA_T                  save_data;      // Cam data in CAM_DATA

    BYTE                    reserved[460];
}   IRF_IR_DATA_HEADER_T;
```

IRF_SAVEDATA_T (partly):

```
typedef struct strSAVEDATA
{
    union {
        struct
        {
            unsigned int        crc;                //  CRC Data
            unsigned char       ver;                //  Setup Data Version  ( CG Model : 0x20 )
            unsigned char       sensor;             //  Sensor Type ( 0x00 : CX320, 0x01 : CX640, 0x20 : CG QVGA, 0x21 : CG VGA )
            
            unsigned char       show_isotherm;      //  CX Model Only
            unsigned char       alarm1_duration;    //  CX Model Only
            unsigned char       alarm2_duration;    //  CX Model Only

            struct {
                unsigned char flag;                 //  ROI Function Mask ( 0x01 : Enable, 0x02 : Exclude )
                unsigned short x1;                  //  Position (x2)
                unsigned short y1;                  //  Position (x2)
                unsigned short x2;                  //  Position (x2)
                unsigned short y2;                  //  Position (x2)
            }   roi[2];                             //  CX Model Only
        };

           unsigned char        reserved1[128];
    };
}   IRF_SAVEDATA_T;
```

I know that C# doesn't support unions and alternative to them would be use FieldOffset attribute. So I've recreated this struct like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct IRF_SAVEDATA_T
{

[FieldOffset(0)] public uint crc;

[FieldOffset(0)] public byte ver;

[FieldOffset(0)] public byte sensor;

[FieldOffset(0)] public byte show_isotherm;

[FieldOffset(0)] public byte alarm1_duration;

[FieldOffset(0)] public byte alarm2_duration;

[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 2)] [FieldOffset(0)] public roi[] roi;
```

But there is an error pops up when I try to start programm:

> TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'XXX.IRF_SAVEDATA_T' because it
> contains an object field at offset 0 that is incorrectly aligned or
> overlapped by a non-object field

I think the source of an error is:

```
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 2)] [FieldOffset(0)] public roi[] roi;
```

to re-create in C# this anonymous struct which initializes array roi, i've created new struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct roi
{
    /// <summary>
    /// ROI Function Mask ( 0x01 : Enable, 0x02 : Exclude )
    /// </summary>
    public byte flag;

    /// <summary>
    /// Position (x2)
    /// </summary>
    public ushort x1;

    /// <summary>
    /// Position (x2)
    /// </summary>
    public ushort y1;

    /// <summary>
    /// Position (x2)
    /// </summary>
    public ushort x2;

    /// <summary>
    /// Position (x2)
    /// </summary>
    public ushort y2;
}
```

I think its wrong, but I don't know another way to get roi field in C# struct.

Comment: Omit it and manually marshall it to/from raw bytes?

Comment: I don't know how to do it. It is my first attempt to use C++ from C#

Comment: Do you know how it is packed?  Looking at your inner `struct`, a struct that starts with a `char` and has four `shorts` will have very different layouts depending on your packing and alignment.  It also looks like you are mapping those `shorts` into `bytes`.  Shorts are 16-bits, bytes are 8-bits

Comment: I've changed roi struct according made bytes -> ushort. Error still remains.

Comment: I dont know about packing, all i have is dll and it header file where struct defined

Comment: Your `FieldOffset`s are wrong, they should be sequential, except for the `reserved1` array which should be `0`. but you could solve this problem by just doing the array on the extra bytes. I.e. The `union` is on the outer struct and `reserved1` not anything else is sequential

Comment: That's a fact, you can't overlap an array object with a value, the garbage collector won't be able to figure out whether the object is valid.  The solution is simple, you didn't interpret the union correctly.  It only overlaps the struct with *reserved1*.  Which you don't need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget the union, it does nothing in this case but add padding at the end. The padding is obviously important, but you can just pad it yourself by counting the bytes and ensuring your structure is at least 128 bytes (which is what the second union part sets it as).

This will simplify your definition greatly, no more `FieldOffset` required anywhere, you can just define your fields as normal.

Comment: Thank you, but what about roi[2] is it correct that i' ve created seperate struct for it in c#?

Comment: Thanks again, I re-wrote whole structure hierarchy and managed to successfully call this method from c#